# Should I get my reference through the snapshot when using fire base cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I wrote this simple firebase cloud function just to get familiar with the product!

All it does is copy the data added to "userWriteable/userProfiles/"

In the documentation you always see them using the snapshot returned in the onCreate callback to get a new database reference to write to.

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');

    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();


    exports.copyProfileFunctionA = functions.database.ref('userWriteable/userProfiles/{userId}')
        .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
            // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
            const original = snapshot.val();

            return snapshot.ref.root.child(`userWriteable/userProfileCopies/${context.params.userId}`).set(original);
        });

    exports.copyProfileFunctionB = functions.database.ref('userWriteable/userProfiles/{userId}')
        .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
            // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
            const original = snapshot.val();
            return admin.database().ref(`userWriteable/userProfileCopies/${context.params.userId}`).set(original);
        });
```

Are there a reason for this or could I do it like a did in the function `copyProfileFunctionB`?

Are there any performance/cost benefits of using functionA over functionB ?

Both functions write to "userWriteable/userProfileCopies/".

Is getting the reference through `admin.database()` more expensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's preferable to use the ref that comes in the snapshot, because it's powered by an instance of the admin SDK that's already initialized, and probably already connected.  Initializing and using the Admin SDK directly is OK, but it could cause your function to wait for another connection (if not already connected), and now each server instance running your code is possibly holding two connections to your database.